# Ember.js project - TypeError: session is undefined

Tags: javascript, session, ember.js, typeerror

I'm trying to run an Ember project that I had to upgrade it's packages, but now I run into deprecation issues.

My current issue is that when I press 'login' I see a `TypeError: session is undefined` message when I open the developer console in firefox.

I have no knowledge of Ember really, so to my very limited understanding is that there's a build javascript file that's based off an MCR architecture of little javascript files.

So here's the part of the big one:

```
define('genesis/controllers/login', ['exports', 'ember'], function (exports, _ember) {
  exports['default'] = _ember['default'].Controller.extend({
    loginMessage: "",
    actions: {
      authenticate: function authenticate() {
        var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
            authenticator = 'simple-auth-authenticator:jwt';
        this.set("loginMessage", "");
        var session = this.get('session');
        session.authenticate(authenticator, credentials);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And this is the small one it's based off:

templates/login.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  loginMessage: "",
  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
        authenticator = 'simple-auth-authenticator:jwt';
      this.set("loginMessage", "");
      var session = this.get('session');
      session.authenticate(authenticator, credentials);
    }
  }
});
```

I had to change `Ember.ObjectController.extend` to `Ember.Controller.extend` due to deprecation.

Comment: Assuming `session` is a service, you need to inject it into the controller in order to be able to use it. Check https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `session` is a service, you need to inject it into the controller in order to be able to use it. Without injecting, `this.get('session')` would return undefined.

Check [this documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services) on more details about dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that during the upgrade I had removed one package from package.json named 
`ember-simple-auth-token`, but I'll give credit to Charizard for letting me find it due to his answer.

I also had to make some tiny changes to the template file.

templates/login.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  loginMessage: "",
  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
        authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
      this.set("loginMessage", "");
      this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials);
    }
  }
});
```